# Get the value of variables in dir(class)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a class in python that groups a bunch of similar variables together and then assembles them into a string. I'm hoping to avoid having to manually type out each variable in the generateString method, so I want to use something like:

```
for variable in dir(class):
    if variable[:1] == '_':
        recordString += variable
```

But currently it just returns a string that has all of the variable names. Is there a way to get at the value of the variable?

Comment: `getattr(class, variable)`?

Comment: [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: Yup, that does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to dynamically access attributes:

```
recordString += getattr(classobj, variable)
```

However, you probably do *not* want to use `dir()` here. `dir()` provides you with a list of attributes on the instance, class and base classes, while you appear to want to find only attributes found directly on the object.

You can use the [`vars()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) instead, which returns a *dictionary*, letting you use `items()` to get both name and value:

```
for variable, value in vars(classobj).items():
    if variable[:1] == '_':
        recordString += value
```

Comment: This looks much better than what I have. The only problem is that I'm getting a Runtime Error saying that the size of the dictionary is changing during iteration.

Comment: @mpthrapp: are you altering attributes on the class itself? You can get a copy of the items first (with `list()`).